# How does the tflite model "conv_actions_tflite" , provided by speech command recognition android demo has been converted?

Tags: python, tensorflow, speech-recognition, tensorflow-lite

I used lite Converter to convert my model of `pb format` to `tflite format` in terminal but it didn't work well.

But when I used the `tflite model` provided by `speech command android demo`, it works pretty well. So I want to know how this model was converted?

https://github.com/tensorflow/docs/blob/master/site/en/r1/tutorials/sequences/audio_recognition.md

Using the above link i trained the model with the below command

`(base) unizen@admin:~/tensorflow/tensorflow/examples/speech_commands$ python train.py`

When the model is saved after the training, I have created frozen model using the below code

```
(base) unizen@admin:~/tensorflow/tensorflow/examples/speech_commands$ python freeze.py \
--start_checkpoint=/tmp/speech_commands_train/conv.ckpt-18000 \
--output_file=/tmp/my_frozen_graph.pb
```

But when i tried converting `.pb format` to `tflite format`

```
(base) unizen@admin:~/tensorflow/tensorflow/examples/speech_commands$  tflite_convert \
--saved_model_dir  /home/unizen/Downloads/my_frozen_graph.pb \
--input_format TENSORFLOW_GRAPHDEF \
--input_arrays decoded_sample_data \
--input_shapes 16000,1 \
--output_arrays labels_softmax \
--output_format TFLITE \
--output_file /tmp/sprc.tflite \
--allow_custom_ops
```

the error is

```
(base) unizen@admin:~/tensorflow/tensorflow/examples/speech_commands$ python usage: tflite_convert [-h] --output_file OUTPUT_FILE
                      (--saved_model_dir SAVED_MODEL_DIR | --keras_model_file KERAS_MODEL_FILE)
tflite_convert: error: one of the arguments --saved_model_dir --keras_model_file is required.
```

kindly provide the solution for conversion of frozen model to tflite model

Comment: The documentation for tflite_convert is here: https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert/cmdline_examples. Could you try without adding "python" at the beginning?

Comment: I actually tried that. I did run the code without adding python at the beginning.I mistakenly posted with python in the question.But the way thanks for the reply.If you come up with the solution, please do post here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This

```
tflite_convert: error: one of the arguments --saved_model_dir --keras_model_file is required.
```

indicates, that you are using tensorflow >= 2.0.0.
Frozen graphs (.pb) are not used anymore since 2.0.0 and developers should save their models as "saved models" or keras models, thus the `tflite_convert` command does not support it anymore.
But if you install for example tensorflow 1.15 you should be able to convert it like so:

```
tflite_convert
--output_file=/output.tflite
--graph_def_file /path/to/my_frozen_graph.pb \
--input_arrays decoded_sample_data,decoded_sample_data:1 \
--output_arrays labels_softmax \
--allow_custom_ops
```

Or if you don't want to install tensorflow 1.15 just do it with the python API and `tf.compat.v1`:

```
import tensorflow as tf

converter = tf.compat.v1.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_frozen_graph("./conv_actions_frozen.pb", input_arrays=['decoded_sample_data', 'decoded_sample_data:1'], output_arrays=['labels_softmax'])
converter.allow_custom_ops=True
tflite_model = converter.convert()
open("output.tflite", "wb").write(model)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and it is working. I have seen how the frozen model(conv_actions_frozen.pb) file is created in another question(#59443695) where you have answered that it has been made from "old examples android code(https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/android/src/org/tensorflow/demo/SpeechActivity.java)".  Do you know how can we train more words(like zero to nine) in addition to those 10 words in that old examples android code?.

Comment: Yes, you can! I already managed to do this and trained a little name recognition.
I would refer to https://github.com/tensorflow/docs/blob/master/site/en/r1/tutorials/sequences/audio_recognition.md. In short: train on your audio data with train.py, freeze the graph with freeze.py and convert it to tflite with the code above in my post.

Comment: Depending on your demand I would record each word you want to train 50-100 times (not sure if that's correct, I've recorded each word 15 times and it performed meh). Make sure the audio you are recording is wav, 1s long, 16000Hz and 1-Channel Mono.

Comment: Sorry if this is a little bit confusing with old and new :D
But the converted model from my comment above *will work* with the new android code example, but not with the old android example because the old android example doesn't work with tflite models.
The documentation for training I posted is for training the old model which works with the new android code when converted to tflite.

Comment: To make it clear:
- old android example: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/android/src/org/tensorflow/demo/SpeechActivity.java
-> uses normal model from old example https://github.com/tensorflow/docs/blob/master/site/en/r1/tutorials/sequences/audio_recognition.md
- new android example: https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/speech_commands/android
-> uses tflite model converted from _old_ example https://github.com/tensorflow/docs/blob/master/site/en/r1/tutorials/sequences/audio_recognition.md

Comment: After following the steps train.py and freeze.py from "https://github.com/tensorflow/docs/blob/master/site/en/r1/tutorials/sequences/audio_recognition.md", The inputs of my frozen model(https://imgur.com/a/JtNVkHw)  is quite different from the conv_actions_frozen.pb(https://imgur.com/a/KJXExbV) you mentioned above. Even the tflite models are having the same difference in the inputs and when I am running it on android studio, It is getting crashed.
 
PS: My Python version is 3.7.3 and Tensor flow version is 2.1.0